# Angular 2, binding pageshow event

Tags: google-chrome, angular, safari

I'm writing some code to prevent accidental exiting from my web application.

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
 leaving($event) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
    return false;
 }

 @HostListener('pageshow',['$event'])
 safari(e) {
     if (e.persisted) {
         window.location.reload();
     }
 }
```

The first `beforeunload` listener works correctly, prevents page from being exited or reloaded, and handles edge cases by pushing the user to home. The second `pageshow` is to handle cases where the user has navigated away, and re-enters via the back/forward buttons on safari, as it handles caching and navigation differently to Chrome.

The `pageshow` event never fires at all, on either browser - am I doing something wrong with the binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have attach window listener: `@HostListener('window:pageshow', ['$event'])`